# SQL Server CPU Usage Troubleshooting

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, cpu-usage

There are a couple of query executed by the mt application. During the executing I am seeing the CPU usage reaches 100%. I am looking for the troubleshoot method for this.

As of now, I progressed as below:

- Using the SQL Server Profiler, i found a couple of query has CPU coulmn value as: 41000. So i feel this query needs to be tuned.
- To analyze the query, i run Query->Analyze query in Database Engine Tuning Adviser. and found that Estimated Improvement is 0%. If this is the case, i feel query is good.

I need to understand next what. What i need to do to troubleshoot further. or How to address this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is no use without information on what these queries are and what they do.

Comment: The queries are lengthy, so i did not put. But it only reads the data base using select query with cte.

Comment: And we know nothing about that database or that CTE, so there is nothing that can be said, except for pointless speculation. How do we know that database isn't gigantic? Or the CTE doesn't call 85329 inefficient functions? There is no info to work with here.